# python, subprocess (call or popen) works in terminal but not in Gnome Schedule User Guide V2.2

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess, wget, scheduler

I am trying to call wget from my python (2.75) script:

```
cmd = ['wget', 'https://192.168.0.1/003/', '--tries=5', '--http-user=foo', '--http-passwd=bar', '--auth-no-challenge', '--no-check-certificate', '--output-document=temp/page.html']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
# same with subprocess.call(cmd)
```

it works fine in the IDE (eclipse), also in a terminal, but when I try to run it from Gnome Schedule User Guide V2.2, I get the following:

```
--2013-08-16 11:27:35--  https://192.168.0.1/003/
Connecting to 192.168.0.1:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify 192.168.0.1's certificate, issued by `blabla': Self-signed certificate encountered.
ERROR: no certificate subject alternative name matches requested host name `192.168.0.1'.
To connect to 192.168.0.1 insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
--2013-08-16 11:27:37--  http://--tries=5/
Resolving --tries=5 (--tries=5)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `--tries=5'
--2013-08-16 11:27:37--  http://--http-user=foo/
Resolving --http-user=foo (--http-user=foo)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `--http-user=foo'
--2013-08-16 11:27:37--  http://--http-passwd=bar/
Resolving --http-passwd=bar (--http-passwd=bar)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `--http-passwd=bar'
--2013-08-16 11:27:37--  http://--auth-no-challenge/
Resolving --auth-no-challenge (--auth-no-challenge)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `--auth-no-challenge'
--2013-08-16 11:27:37--  http://--no-check-certificate/
Resolving --no-check-certificate (--no-check-certificate)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `--no-check-certificate'
--2013-08-16 11:27:37--  http://--output-document=temp/page.html
Resolving --output-document=temp (--output-document=temp)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `--output-document=temp'
```

...so instead of taking the command "wget arg1 arg2 arg3...", it seems to try to run:
"wget arg1"
"wget arg2"
"wget arg3"
...

any clue of what could make a different result when run from the scheduler?

the command I use in the scheduler is:
    "python /home/python/Download/Download.py"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself, by moving the second argument in the last position:

```
cmd = ['wget', '--tries=5', '--http-user=foo', '--http-passwd=bar', '--auth-no-challenge', '--no-check-certificate', '--output-document=temp/page.html', 'https://192.168.0.1/003/']
```

It works now, but I still wonder why in terminal or in the IDE it worked fine and not when run from the scheduler...